# Slideshow with ffmpeg results in stuttery, unseekable, incorrect length file

Tags: command-line, video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, h.264

I'm using `ffmpeg` to show images for different durations in a video:

(command taken from example on this [page](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow))

`ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -vsync vfr -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4`

Here what `input.txt` roughly looks like:

```
file '/path/to/im1.png'
duration 123
file '/path/to/im2.png'
duration 234
file '/path/to/im3.png'
duration 235
file '/path/to/im4.png'
duration 400
file '/path/to/im4.png'
```

The resulting file has trouble playing back in `mpv`, `Movies and TV` (windows), and `VLC`. On a hunch, I ran the file through `ffmpeg` again to see I could 'fix' the output file (command used: `ffmpeg -i in.mp4 out.mp4`). `out.mp4` was much larger than `in.mp4` (around an order of magnitude), but played smoothly, showed progress correctly, and was able to seek properly. What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `-vsync vfr` flag, ffmpeg will insert the images at time 0, 123, 357..etc with no frames in between. A video player normally works with streams where adjacent frames are centiseconds apart, so its buffering/caching system are designed with that expectation. You could get away with the VFR mode if durations were in the single-digit seconds, but not here. I would recommend CFR mode with a low frame rate.

So,

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -vsync cfr -r 2 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

Comment: Ahh, so if I'm understanding correctly it's kinda the players faults for not handling this valid, but weird video?

Comment: You could say that, but fault is a harsh term. Any software will be designed for vanilla and common edge cases.

Comment: Strangely enough, running my original command and then passing it through ffmpeg again is faster then just using `-vsync cfr` (around 4x faster)

Comment: Vsync cfr is default for mp4 output. The difference will be due to the framerate.